# Facebook Graph API sometimes returns incorrect lat/long for places. How do you correct these lat/lon errors?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Here's an example of a facebook place where the latitude and longitude are incorrect even though the street address is correct.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=261035103969287

The location returned looks like this:

```
"location": {
  "street": "1299 18th Street", 
  "city": "San Francisco", 
  "state": "CA", 
  "country": "United States", 
  "zip": "94107", 
  "latitude": 37.748034283333, 
  "longitude": -122.39304696667
},
```

Facebook has a places editor https://www.facebook.com/places/editor but I cannot figure out how to suggest an updated lat/lon.